# Can't send message from lambda to aws sqs and no error is returned from aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to send a message from my lambda function to a sqs queue that is already created. When I run the code, it literally stops the execution and no feedback is provided by aws-sdk.

I also have a function to read from the queue when I insert the messages manually, I use the same code to create the session. Which I believe can be used on both situations.

Then I tried to use the code provided by amazon but the outcome was the same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/sqs-example-receive-message.html

The only difference on my code is how I create the session. Like I mentioned above, that's the same way I use to read messages when they are inserted manually in the queue. On that function everything seems perfect.

```
func sendToOrderQueue(rID string, c Course) error {                            
  log.Println(1)
   var err error                                                                    
   sess := session.Must(session.New(&aws.Config{
      Region: aws.String("eu-central-1"),                                                                        
   }), err)                                            
   svc := sqs.New(sess)                                                              
   log.Println(2)                                                                    

   url := "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXX/myqueue"              

   log.Println(3)                                                                         
   result, err := svc.SendMessage(&sqs.SendMessageInput{                            
     DelaySeconds: aws.Int64(10),                                                    
     MessageAttributes: map[string]*sqs.MessageAttributeValue{                      
       "Title": &sqs.MessageAttributeValue{                                          
         DataType:    aws.String("String"),                                          
         StringValue: aws.String("The Whistler"),                                    
       },                                                                            
       "Author": &sqs.MessageAttributeValue{                                        
         DataType:    aws.String("String"),                                          
         StringValue: aws.String("John Grisham"),                                    
       },                                                                            
       "WeeksOn": &sqs.MessageAttributeValue{                                        
         DataType:    aws.String("Number"),                                          
         StringValue: aws.String("6"),                                              
       },                                                                            
     },                                                                              
     MessageBody: aws.String("Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 12/11/2016."),    
     QueueUrl:    &url,                                                              
   })
    log.Println(4)

   if err != nil {                                                              
     log.Println("Error", err)                                                  
      return err                                                                  
    }                                                                            

   log.Println(5, *result.MessageId, err)                                        
   return err                                                                    
  }
```

Also, my serverless.yaml

```
service: client                                                          
  frameworkVersion: ">=1.28.0 <2.0.0"                                            

  provider:                                                                      
    name: aws                                                                    
    runtime: go1.x                                                                
    vpc: ${file(../security.yaml):vpc}                                            

  package:                                                                        
   exclude:                                                                      
     - ./**                                                                      
   include:                                                                      
     - ./bin/**                                                                  

  functions:
   postFunction:                                                    
    handler: bin/post                                                        
    environment:                                                                  
      REDIS_URL: ${file(../env.yaml):environment.REDIS_URL}                      
      HASH_KEY: ${file(../env.yaml):environment.HASH_KEY}
    events:                                                                      
     - http:                                                                      
        path: /func                                                            
        method: post                                                              
        cors: ${file(../cors.yaml):cors}
```

Checking the cloudwatch's logs the execution **prints** *1*, *2*, *3* and nothing else. **No** *4*, **no** *Error* and **no** *5*.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue.
Look in CloudWatch labmda's logs. There is an error like

> Task timed out after 10.01 seconds

This is a lambda's timeout. You have no errors regarding sqs because timeout of lambda is smaller than default timeout of http.Client inside `svc.SendMessage` (sendMessage is just a POST request to aws api) and lambda is terminated before it gets any response from sqs. 10 seconds for lambda and 30 seconds for http request in my case. Add `LogLevel` to `aws.Config` like this:

`&aws.Config{
      LogLevel: aws.LogLevel(aws.LogDebug),
}`

and you will see this http request in CloudWatch logs. Also you can set lambda's timeout to 2-3 times bigger than http.Client timeout and you will see retries in logs (3 retries by default).

Looks like lambda can't resolve the host of sqs or something like this because I get the same errors when VPC is configured wrong.

**UPD**
Fixed the problem. If you use VPC in your lambda it should have special configuration to access to SQS from VPC. Take a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-sending-messages-from-vpc.html

Comment: Thanks - this was a big help. I needed to make sure to have a security group which allowed ALL traffic, not just TCP, both in and out. This security group was assigned to the SQS endpoint in my vpc.